# Using the lc attribute on a multilingual Voog website

Tags: voog

I have a quick a quick question about the Voog (http://www.voog.com) platform.

How can I change the translation files? I want to use the "lc" attribute, for example: `{{ 'Previous posts' | lc }}`
As of now, there is displayed "translation missing: en.app.site.previous posts”.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the built in translations for your layouts at http://www.voog.com/developers/markup/basics/i18n#built-in-translations.

In your case, there are already built in translations for previous/next texts:

`{{ 'previous' | lc }}`
`{{ ’next' | lc }}`

However, to add custom translations into a layout, proceed with the following steps:

1. Add a new component in the design editor (for example, "Translations")
2. Use `{% include %}` to include it into preferred layouts (for example, `{% include "Translations" %}` in the Blog article layout).
3. Then you can use `{% case %}` to add translations into the component.

Here is an example (obviously, the comment isn't necessary):

```
{% case page.language_code %}
{% when 'et' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Previous posts in Estonian' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Next posts in Estonian' %}
{% when 'fi' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Previous posts in Finnish' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Next posts in Finnish' %}
{% when 'lv' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Previous posts in Latvian' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Next posts in Latvian' %}
{% else %}
{% comment %}All langugages that are not defined above, use this fallback. Using English might be a good idea{% endcomment %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Previous posts' %}
{% assign translation_prev_post = 'Next posts' %}
{% endcase %}
```

4. Finally, you can add these to display in specific places inside the layout.

For example, `{{ translation_prev_post }}` or `{{ translation_next_post }}` after the article component.